# registering an Android regId to parse.com push installation manually

Tags: parse-platform, push-notification, cordova-plugins

I have a GCM regId from a cordova push plugin that I'd like to register with a parse.com push server so that I can send it push messages.

I saw a stackoverflow post saying I should set the installation manually by

```
POST https://api.parse.com/1/installations

{"deviceType": "android", "WHATSHOULDTHISBE?": "MYREGID", "channels": [""]}
```

The example showed a deviceToken which is an iOS example, but I'm not sure where regId would fit in an Android example.  I don't see the property listed in any of the parse documentation for the installation object.

Should I not be using the REST api and instead be using the js library to set this somehow?

Comment: If you want to use the REST-API to add an installation to your Parse app, there is a section in the documentation covering what you have to do. https://www.parse.com/docs/rest#push

Answer (score 1):

Registering in parse can be done by adding these lines

```
Parse.initialize(this, getString(R.string.parse_application_id), getString(R.string.parse_client_key));
ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
```

These have to be the first few lines on the activity or application based on where you want to register it.

These lines will register the device with parse. You can send broadcast notification from the parse console and you will receive it.

If you want to get the device token from parse, then you need to write a callback in saveInBackground() like this

```
ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            String deviceToken = (String) ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().get("deviceToken");
        }
    });
```

Hope this helps.